# Google Play Alpha Version needs unintall first

Tags: android, testing

I have a published app and just uploaded an alpha version with higher version no. I have  also defined a google group as a tester group. 
The members in this group should unistall and install again my app in order to get the new alpha version? 
Or this is done automatically?

Comment: Yes, but the testers need to opt in to the Alpha.

Comment: what to you mean by "opt  in to the alpha"?

Comment: When you setup the Alpha test you should be prompted with a URL that you need to send to your testers.  They will need to click the link to opt-in to the test.   Users can opt-out at anytime with the same link and uninstall and revert back to the Production version.